# Remove past migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I created quite a lot of migrations since the beginning of my rails app. Some of them where just for test purposes. I now have a lot of migrations that are totally useless (eg: create a table in a migration and drop it in the next one).

As schema.rb get updated once db:migrate is ran, is it possible to delete all the migrations and to start from the actual content of schema.rb ?

Comment: you could use `rake db:schema:load`

Comment: and delete all migration files ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can (and probably should) remove older migrations. There will come a point where your old migrations might no longer work since your model code will depend on later versions of your schema.

So by all means delete the migrations (you have them under source control, right?), and use

```
rake db:schema:load
```

to initialize a new database if you need to.

UPDATE: The Rails guide now has something similar to say about this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Comment: Use `rake db:schema:load` instead of `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: No. `rake db:schema:load` dumps your current database and re-creates it from `schema.rb`. `rake db:migrate` applies any outstanding migrations to the existing database.

Comment: Why is that important to have them in source control if I have the last version of schema.rb ? Should not be that one the important guy ?

Comment: You should have EVERYTHING in source control - that way, you can remove (or modify) anything without having to worry about whether you ever need it again. because you can always recover a previous version.

Comment: I always have everything in source control, but my question was more to know if one can get rid of the very old migration definitively. If I am to deploy my application on a brand new server, would schema.rb be sufficient ?

Comment: IMHO this is very dangerous advice Thilo -- because then people start relying on the db/schema.rb file, and once they ever edit it by hand, or forget to check it in, they could really mess up their schema, and totally circumvent the whole purpose of migrations

Comment: @Tilo I respectfully disagree. "and once they ever edit it by hand" is negated by using source control. "or forget to check it in" is negated by using source control *properly*. `schema.rb` should be your authoritative source. They *should* rely on it, and not migrations, IMO.

Comment: See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you: "There is no need (and it is error prone) to deploy a new instance of an app by replaying the entire migration history. It is much simpler and faster to just load into the database a description of the current schema."

Comment: so how do you prevent accidental edits further down the line? I'm pointing this out because I've seen this happen IRL.

Comment: How do you prevent accidental edits to your migrations? Or any other file for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

a better way to do this is to do the following...

Once you reach a milestone in your project, and you are certain you don't want to migrate below that version of the DB, 
you can replace your large number of migration files with a single migration file, which you can then use as the new "initial" migration which bundles-up everything which was done up to that date.

After that: continue to use migrations in your project!

Never edit your schema.rb file by hand.. and never load the db/schema.rb file unless it's for something like disaster recovery.

You have no 100% guarantee that the file which is checked-in to version control is the latest or even the correct version.

It is much safer to migrate up and down, and just bundle-up a large amount of migrations in one single migration file instead.

By loading the schema.rb file manually, you totally circumvent the safety net which the migrations provide. That's just not a good idea.